# Coroutine not stopping on a condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a condition wherein if it reaches the certain condition the coroutine will stop, it reaches the condition but coroutine still continues

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] getCount;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(startCounting());
    }
    void Update()
    {
        getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemyCollider");
    }

    Coroutine myRoutine = null;
    int count;
    IEnumerator startCounting()
    {
        count++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Debug.Log("CURRENT COUNTER IS " +count);
        if (getCount.Length == 3)
        {
            Debug.Log("ENEMY COUNTER HAS REACHED " + count);
            StopAllCoroutines();
        }

        else if (getCount.Length == 6)
        {
            Debug.Log("ENEMY COUNTER HAS REACHED " + count);
            StopAllCoroutines();
        }
        StartCoroutine(startCounting());
    }
}
```

I tried storing it on a `Coroutine myCoroutine` then `StopCoroutine(myCoroutine)` but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the condition you will still reach the line

```
StartCoroutine(startCounting());
```

which will start the routine again!

```
StopAllCorouines();
```

only means they will not receive their **next** `MoveNext` call, it doesn't instantly interrupt this routine. This you could achieve by rather using

```
yield break;
```

which basically is the `IEnumerator` equivalent of a `return` in a normal method.

---

However, instead of going recursive and additionally run `Update` in parallel I would rather stick to either only `Update` and do

```
public class enemyCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] getCount;

    private float timer;
    private int count;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        count = 0;
        timer = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer >= 1f)
        {
            count++;
            Debug.Log("CURRENT COUNTER IS " + count);

            timer -= 1f;

            var getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemyCollider");
            if(getCount.Length == 3 || getCount.Length == 6)
            {
                Debug.Log("ENEMY COUNTER HAS REACHED " + count);
                enableed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want to use a Coroutine do e.g.

```
public class enemyCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(startCounting());
    }

    private IEnumerator Counting()
    {
        var count = 0f;

        var getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemyCollider");

        while(getCount != 3 && getCount != 6)
        {
            count++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

            Debug.Log("CURRENT COUNTER IS " + count);

            getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemyCollider");
        }

        Debug.Log("ENEMY COUNTER HAS REACHED " + count);
    }
}
```